# CosmosDb c# SDK is not working on contrary to the Rest Api

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am using CosmosDb Sdk with nuget `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core 2.1.0` with `.NetStandard 2.0`.

I am using this query to fetch documents

```
var client client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(config.CosmosDbEndPointUrl), config.CosmosDbPrimaryKey);
var partitionKey = "siteId"; // the partition key is defined as /siteId, I tried both, still not working
var queryOptions = new FeedOptions
{
  MaxItemCount = 500,
  EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true,
  PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey)
};

var auditQuery = client
    .CreateDocumentQuery<AuditDTO>(
     UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_databaseName, _collectionName), queryOptions)
        .Where(f => f.Status == AuditStatus.Pending)
        .AsDocumentQuery();

var results = new List<AuditDTO>();
while (auditQuery.HasMoreResults)
{
  var audits = await auditQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<AuditDTO>();
  results.AddRange(audits);
}
```

This query returns 0 document.

I based my query on [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-get-started#Query)

I thought some parameters were incorrect so, I tried to use the Rest Api, code based on [this example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-dotnet/blob/master/samples/rest-from-.net/Program.cs) (see comment `EXECUTE a query`)

```
var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
string response = string.Empty;
string authHeader = string.Empty;
string verb = string.Empty;
string resourceType = string.Empty;
string resourceId = string.Empty;
string resourceLink = string.Empty;
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-date", utc_date);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", "2017-02-22");

verb = "POST";
resourceType = "docs";
resourceLink = $"dbs/{databaseId}/colls/{collectionId}/docs";
resourceId = (idBased) ? $"dbs/{databaseId}/colls/{collectionId}" : collectionId.ToLowerInvariant();

authHeader = GenerateMasterKeyAuthorizationSignature(verb, resourceId, resourceType, masterKey, "master", "1.0");

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("authorization");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authorization", authHeader);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-documentdb-isquery", "True");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition", "true");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-partition-key", "[\"siteId\"]");

var qry = new SqlQuerySpec { query = "SELECT * FROM root WHERE (root[\"status\"] = 0)" };
var r = await client.PostWithNoCharSetAsync(new Uri(baseUri, resourceLink), qry);
var s = await r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Using the Rest Api returns 1 document as I am expecting.

I tried to deserialize the response to the class AuditDTO, it works, so, no problem with my model.

I don't understand why the Rest Api is working and not the .Net Sdk.

There is no authorization exception, no error message. I just get 0 document.

I am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is really misleading.

To enable CrossPartition queries to query all partitions, you just need to set `EnableCrossPartitionQuery` to true and that's it!

```
var queryOptions = new FeedOptions
{
  MaxItemCount = 500,
  EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true
};
```

As Nick Chapsas said, if you need to search a specific partition, set the `PartitionKey` property to the value of the partition you want to search against.

Here is [a sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-dotnet/blob/master/samples/code-samples/Queries/Program.cs#L736-L882) I found on Azure GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

```
var partitionKey = "siteId";
var queryOptions = new FeedOptions
{
  MaxItemCount = 500,
  EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true,
  PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey)
};
```

Your problem is on the partition key.
Partition key is expected to be the value of the partition key not the definition.

This means that the `partitionKey` value on `FeedOptions` should look like this `59c49da3-b398-4db7-aff4-d2129353e3a8` (assuming it's a guid) not this `siteId`.

The correct FeedOptions Object would look like this:

```
var partitionKey = "59c49da3-b398-4db7-aff4-d2129353e3a8";
var queryOptions = new FeedOptions
{
  MaxItemCount = 500,
  EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true,
  PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey)
};
```